# Inequality on characteristic functions (probability theory)

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Show that for every real characteristic function $\phi(t)$ we have

$$1-\phi(2t) \le 4(1-\phi(t))$$

I am not sure where to begin. It seems I am missing some formula or theorem, or is it really that I have to write it out by definition and integrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate with respect to the distribution of the random variable the inequality $$1-\cos(2tx)=2-2\cos^2(tx)=2(1+\cos(tx))(1-\cos(tx))\leqslant4(1-\cos(tx)).$$

Comment: I got a close result,
$1-\int {cos(2txf(x)dx} \le 4 (1- \int {cos(tx)f(x)dx})$

but how do i get the i*sin(2tx) and i*sin(tx) under the integral?

Comment: I know i can't compare complex numbers, but i can get $sin(2tx) \le 4 sin(tx)$. Is it allowed to integrate it over i*F(x)? then i could just add both inequalities.

Comment: I do not know if the questions you ask in your two comments to my answer are still bothering you but in any case, I fail to see how they would be related to my solution. (Note that $\sin(2tx)\leqslant4\sin(tx)$ is not always true--fortunately, sines are nowhere needed in the solution.)