# Inequality in characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Let $\phi$ be a characteristic function of random variable $X$. Prove that $1-|\phi(2u)|^2\leq 4(1-|\phi(u)|^2)$.
I don't even have a clue how to start this.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880331/inequality-on-characteristic-functions-probability-theory

Comment: I have seen that question. What I want to know is how to convert this question into that form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that: $$\phi_{-X}(u)=\mathbb Ee^{-iuX}=\mathbb E\overline{e^{iuX}}=\overline{\mathbb Ee^{iuX}}=\overline{\phi_X(u)}$$

Showing that - if $\phi(u)$ is a characteristic function - then so is $\overline{\phi(u)}$.

Also it is well known that a product of characteristic functions is again a characteristic function.

This together tells us that $|\phi(u)|^2=\phi(u)\overline{\phi(u)}$ is a characteristic function so [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/880339/75923) on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/880331/75923) (the link provided by bubububub) proves the statement.

Also you can take a look at the first part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2214271/75923).